# I have an issue printing the length of a string from the command line without using strlen?

Tags: c, char, command-line-arguments

Hello there basically what my program is meant to do is when the user enters a string from the command line it will print the word and the size.

E.g

```
./commandline hello world
```

Output:

hello

world

2

What I'm trying to do is add a method that will print its length without using `strlen` so output should be length 10 for the example above.

This is my code bare in mind i am new to c.

```
int main(int args, char *argv[]){
     for(int i =1; i <args; i++){
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        size_t(argv[i]);
     }
     printf("%d\n", args -1);
}
size_t string_length( char *argv[]){
    int length = 0;
    while(argv[length]!='\0')  
    {
        length++;
        printf("%i\n", length);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My program does not print length only prints the string entered and the size.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: That code should not even compile, much less run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for(int i =1; i <args; i++){
     printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
     size_t(argv[i]);
 }
 printf("%d\n", args -1);
```

Here you're *not calling your function anywhere*. Your program just prints the arguments and the number of them. `size_t(argv[i]);` merely casts `argv[i]` to a *type* called `size_t`. Certainly, that's not what you want. Replace it with `string_length(argv[i]);`. Note that you'd better change the type of the first argument of this function.

What's more, you should return `length` in your `string_length` function.

```
size_t string_length( char *arg){
    size_t length = 0;
    while(arg[length])  
    {
        length++;
    }
return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
size_t string_length( char *argv[]);
int main(int args, char *argv[]){
     for(int i =1; i <args; i++){
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        string_length(argv[i]);
     }
     printf("%d\n", args -1);
}

size_t string_length( char *argv[]){


    int length = 0;
    while(argv[length]!='\0')  
    {
        length++;

    }
    printf("%i\n", length);
    return length;

}
```